# Use class to pass parameters as list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I'm working on a simple chatscreen UI in Flutter. There's a user-defined widget MessageBubble that accepts three parameters: sender (String), text (String), isMe (bool). Currently it is being passed static values one by one, like this:

```
List<MessageBubble> messages = [
    MessageBubble(
      sender: "Me",
      text: "Hi!",
      isMe: true,
    ),
    MessageBubble(
      sender: "Not Me",
      text: "Hey, hi!",
      isMe: false,
    ),
];
```

What I want to do instead, is I've created a class BubbleData like this:

```
class BubbleData {
    List <String> sender = ['Not Me', 'Not Me'];
    List <String> text = ['Hey Hi', "What's new?"];
    List <bool> isMe = [false, false];
}
```

Now the problem at hand lies that how do I iterate these listitems through the MessageBubble using a ListView builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer of Akade.
You can use it in a listView like this:

```
 class MyBubbleList extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<BubbleData> bubbles = [
   BubbleData(sender: 'Not Me', text: 'Hey Mi', isMe: false),
   BubbleData(sender: 'Not Me', text: 'What\'s new?', isMe: false)
];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //here the ListView part
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount:bubbles.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
             return Container(child:Text(bubbles[index].text));
      },);
  }
}
```

You can check more info in Flutter documentation. You will find  very good video tutorial on how to use ListView.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked. Instead of returning a Text, I returned a MessageBubble and passed arguments like this - sender: bubbles[index].sender, text: bubbles[index].text, isMe: bubbles[index].isMe

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a better approach would be to define your BubbleData as follows:

```
class BubbleData{
   String sender;
   String text;
   bool isMe;

   BubbleData({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe});
}
```

Then you create a list that can be iterated, with your data:

```
List<BubbleData> bubbles = [
   BubbleData(sender: 'Not Me', text: 'Hey Mi', isMe: false),
   BubbleData(sender: 'Not Me', text: 'What\'s new?', isMe: false)
];
```

Next step will be to map and convert to a MessageBubble's list:

```
List<MessageBubble> messages = bubbles.map((bubble) =>
   MessageBubble(
      sender: bubble.sender, 
      text: bubble.text, 
      isMe: bubble.isMe
   )
).toList();
```

Comment: How do I iterate this through a ListView.builder?

Comment: Please tell me how do I use the List messages in a ListView.builder?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this:

```
BubbleData data = BubbleData();  //instantiating

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.sender.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data.text[index]),         //iterating
          subtitle: Text(data.sender[index]),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited your post here because of one more issue I'm facing... Can you please help me?

Comment: Your edit was rejected but if you want we can discuss about the problem in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213627/talking-about-flutter)